# How to do a column sum in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

What is the equivalent of the following in Tensorflow?

```
np.sum(A, axis=1)
```

Comment: Check the docs for [reduce_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_sum)

Comment: Updated link for docs for [reduce_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is tf.reduce_sum which is a bit more powerfull tool for doing so.

```
# 'x' is [[1, 1, 1]
#         [1, 1, 1]]
tf.reduce_sum(x) ==> 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0) ==> [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1) ==> [3, 3]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1, keep_dims=True) ==> [[3], [3]]
tf.reduce_sum(x, [0, 1]) ==> 6
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Why isn't this in the website howto?

Comment: Could you please detail a bit why `tf.reduce_sum(x, [0, 1]) ==> 6`? I tripped up by it.

Comment: @Lemer - you are asking TF to sum over two axes - 0th and 1th, so since the matrix is 2D you end up with the complete sum of all the elements. In general having KD tensor and suming over L axes you end up with (K-L)D tensor, thus for K=L it always outputs a float (0D tensor).

Comment: Is there a difference between `axis=1` and `axis=-1`?

Comment: @LYu i think that as per python syntax, axis=-1 is the last axis of the tensor, so in **this** specific case, they are the same. for ND tensors the two are not the same.

Comment: In TFv2 the name is `keepdims`