# how to loop through each row in a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

I have a 2d tensor in tensorflow,

Let's say for example a 2*4 tensor [[1.,2.,3.,4.],[2.,4.,5.,6.]].

I have a function a() to let each row in the tensor to pass, and then sum over all the results of a(). How to do it (not doing it in the session)?

The output should be a([1.,2.,3.,4.]) + a([2.,4.,5.,6.]), in practice I have a very large tensor with many rows.

This is different from reduce_sum, because the a() function here is quite complex, which cannot be directly used through vectorization.

Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689671/how-to-do-a-column-sum-in-tensorflow

Comment: Hi Phoenix, this seems different from just using reduce_mean.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is the [map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) function in Tensorflow. `map_fn(a, elems)` unpacks a tensor, `elems` along its first dimension into a sequences of slices, and then applies the supplied function `a` to each slice, followed by combining the outputs into a single tensor again by concatenating along the first dimension.

It sounds like what you want is

```
Y = map_fn(a, X)
answer = reduce_sum(Y, axis=0)
```

where `X` is your supplied tensor.